# Why does this instance of getFile work with SVNKit?

Tags: java, svnkit

I'm trying to get a method that I wrote/adapted from the documentation from the SVNKit documentation working but to no avail. I'm trying to print out the contents of a file if it matches a particular revision. The problem is that I'm not sure how to properly use the getfile call. I'm just not sure of the strings that I need to pass to it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
 public static void listEntries(SVNRepository repository, String path, int revision, List<S_File> file_list) throws SVNException {
      Collection entries = repository.getDir(path, revision, null, (Collection) null);
      Iterator iterator = entries.iterator();
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
           SVNDirEntry entry = (SVNDirEntry) iterator.next();

           if (entry.getRevision() == revision) {
                SVNProperties fileProperties = new SVNProperties();
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                S_File toadd = new S_File(entry.getDate(), entry.getName(), entry.getRevision());                


                try {                        
                    SVNNodeKind nodeKind = repository.checkPath(path + entry.getName(), revision); //**PROBLEM HERE**

                    if (nodeKind == SVNNodeKind.NONE) {
                        System.err.println("There is no entry there");
                        //System.exit(1);
                    } else if (nodeKind == SVNNodeKind.DIR) {
                        System.err.println("The entry is a directory while a file was expected.");
                        //System.exit(1);
                    }                        
                    repository.getFile(path + entry.getName( ), revision, fileProperties, baos);


                } catch (SVNException svne) {
                    System.err.println("error while fetching the file contents and properties: " + svne.getMessage());
                    //System.exit(1);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be related to the path in earlier revisions being different, for example a /Repo/components/new/file1.txt [rev 1002] may have been moved from /Repo/components/old/file1.txt [rev 1001]. Trying to get the file1.txt with revision 1001 at path /Repo/components/new/ will throw an SVNException.

SVNRepository class has a [getFileRevisions](http://svnkit.com/kb/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/io/SVNRepository.html#getFileRevisions%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection,%20long,%20long%29) method that returns a Collection where each entry has a path for a given revision number so it is this path that could be passed to the getFile method:

```
String inintPath = "new/file1.txt";
Collection revisions = repo.getFileRevisions(initPath, 
                       null, 0, repo.getLatestRevision());
Iterator iter = revisions.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext())
{
SVNFileRevision rv = (SVNFileRevision) iter.next();

InputStream rtnStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("".getBytes());
    SVNProperties fileProperties = new SVNProperties();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    repo.getFile(rv.getPath(), rv.getRevision(), fileProperties, baos); 
}
```